# Can I set Option Explicit and Option Strict on a Project/Solution level?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I really like the coding speed that VB.NET provides, but I don't like the possibility to forget to declare variable types, return types of functions, etc. and that is why in each class I use:

```
Option Explicit On  
Option Strict On
```

Is there a way to define those two options on the project/solution level?
It is really tedious to copy those two options in each class...
We code with [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) in .NET 4 Client Profile.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes**, you can set these options for the entire project in your project's Properties:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and select "Properties" from the context menu.
2. Click on the "Compile" tab in the list on the left-hand side.
3. Set the values of the comboboxes as desired.

[image: Project properties - Compile tab - Compile Options]

You could also choose to specify these settings **globally** in the Visual Studio options (although this will only affect *new* projects, not existing ones):

1. In the Visual Studio environment, click on the "Tools" menu and select "Options".
2. Expand the "Projects and Solutions" item in the treeview on the left-hand side of the dialog.
3. Select the "VB Defaults" item.
4. Set your "Default project settings" as desired.

[image: VS Options - Projects and Solutions - VB Defaults - Default project settings]

Comment: +1: I strongly recommend having these set globally, and I mean **REALLY STRONGLY RECOMMEND** . . .

Comment: Yes, I agree with Binary Worrier. Your settings should probably look **exactly** like the ones shown here. (Although some might prefer `Option Compare Text`.)

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not put Option Infer On?

Comment: @jeroenh: I discussed that very issue at length with another member recently. It seems that with later versions it's perfectly possible to write good code with `Option Infer On`, but I personally have seen too many mistakes made by leaving it on for my comfort. I prefer to work with as strict of type checking turned on as possible. I'm not sure what the harm is in being explicit; I've seen the harm in *not* being such. Ultimately I suppose it's a gut call.

Comment: @Cody Gray As long as Option Strict On, I have no problem with Option Infer On. The biggest advantages to me are easier refactoring and (somewhat) less verbosity.

Comment: +1 Binary worrier. VB.Net is not installed until you have set `Option Explict On` and `Option Strict On`. I don't usually **SHOUT** much, but **I DO ABOUT THIS**

Comment: @jeroenh @Cody Gray The major advantage of `Option Infer On` is that you can use Linq

Comment: @MarkJ: Oh, is *that* it? That's good to know. I couldn't figure out why everyone always seems to resist my preference to have it off. I don't find myself using Linq very often.

Comment: @Cody Gray Yes, in fact type inference was added to the language [specifically in order to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163345.aspx#S1) make Linq possible. Disclaimer: I don't use Linq much either... one day I must try it out properly and find out what the fuss is about :)

Comment: A point noone's mentioned: Your `Option Strict On`, etc in existing files will override any project-level settings (which is why they worked, of course).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the obvious place is to look in the project options dialog, and lo and behold:

[image: Visual Basic .NET Project Options]