# How to convert total time to minutes

Tags: vb.net

[This was the error msg im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilmSx.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHk9g.png)I have a database that has a row "Total_Time" (time).
It is in the format HH:MM:SS. I need the code to convert the "Total_time" to minutes.

For example, if Total_time = 01:30:00, the answer should be Total_minutes = 90,
and I want to multiply the total_minutes with "Other" (int variable).

Below is what I have tried:

```
  Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click


    con = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Try


        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Vicky-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=customer_details;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
        con.Open()


        Dim cm As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cm = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE Id=@id", con)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox5.Text)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            Dim tt As Double
            tt = dr("Total_Time").ToString
            Dim other As Double
            other = dr("Other").ToString

            Dim str() As String
            Dim strmin As Double
            str = Split(tt.ToString, ":")
            strmin = (CDbl(str(1)) * 60 + CDbl(str(2)) + CDbl(str(3)) / 60).ToString

            Dim total As Decimal
            total = strmin + other
            Label7.Text = total.ToString
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

but  when i click nothing is happening label7 is not displaying any values
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: i have inserted this code for a button  and when i click nothing is happening label7 is not displaying any values

Comment: Don't you mean at the end to put Label7.Text = strmin

Comment: im not getting can you please explain

Comment: what format is Total_Time really stored as in the DB?  Why all the string conversions?

Comment: i need to display the total in the label7.text on the button click

Comment: The Total_Time is in time(7) format -Trevor

Comment: Are you getting results back from your query? You haven't explained what debugging you have done and where the problem is. I would hope that you have at least verified whether your datareader contains any data and thus whether you are going into the loop or whether an exception is being thrown - if so you should definitely tell us what exception is being thrown...

Comment: Turn on Option Strict `tt = dr("Total_Time").ToString` wont compile if `tt` is defined as double

Comment: `While dr.Read()
                Dim Total_Time As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr("Total_Time"))
                Dim minutes As Double = Total_Time.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes
                Dim Other As Double = Val(dr("Other"))
                Dim total As Double = minutes * Other
                Label7.Text = total.ToString
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception`

Comment: this is what the code im using but still not working

Comment: You are erroring out. break on the Catch statement and see what the error is. BUt it looks like your Other value is not a number which would cause it to drop out.

Comment: you ALWAYS should test for dbnull when using databases. DBNull has some weird behaviours in math and Boolean comparisons.

Comment: is the value of "other" is just minutes i.e. integer  or in the HH:MM:SS format ? . I have considered HH:MM:SS in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim Total_minutes As Double = CDate("1:23:45").TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes          ' 83.75
```

To avoid similar errors, I would highly recommend using [`Option Strict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076851/can-i-set-option-explicit-and-option-strict-on-a-project-solution-level)

```
Dim Total_Time As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dr!Total_Time)
Dim Total_minutes# = Total_Time.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes

Dim Other# = Val(dr!Other)
Dim total# = Total_minutes * Other

Label7.Text = total.ToString
```

Comment: I'm curious - why are you answering if you didn't read the question?

Comment: @Chris because I read the title, and might be helpful to others that search for something similar

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    con = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Vicky-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=customer_details;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
        con.Open()

        Dim cm As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cm = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE Id=@id", con)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox5.Text)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()     
            Dim other As TimeSpan           
            Dim tt As TimeSpan

            If TimeSpan.TryParse(dr("Total_Time"), tt) Then
                If TimeSpan.TryParse(dr("Other"), other) Then
                    tt = tt.Add(other)
                Else
                    'Do something like show error message for incorrect data for dr("Other")
                End If
                Label7.Text = tt.TotalMinutes.ToString
            Else
                'Do something like show error message for incorrect data for dr("Total_Time")
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

If time is more than 24:00:00, use below code

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    con = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Vicky-pc\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=customer_details;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
        con.Open()

        Dim cm As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        cm = New SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM customer_details WHERE Id=@id", con)
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox5.Text)
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()     
            Try
                Dim dataTime As String = dr("Total_Time").ToString
                dataTime = dataTime.Split("."c)(0).ToString
                Dim tt As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(dataTime.Split(":"c)(0)), Integer.Parse(dataTime.Split(":"c)(1)), Integer.Parse(dataTime.Split(":"c)(2)))
                dataTime = dr("Other").ToString
                dataTime = dataTime.Split("."c)(0).ToString
                Dim other As New TimeSpan(Integer.Parse(dataTime.Split(":"c)(0)), Integer.Parse(dataTime.Split(":"c)(1)), Integer.Parse(dataTime.Split(":"c)(2)))
                tt = tt.Add(other)
                dataTime = tt.TotalMinutes.ToString

            Catch ex As Exception
                'do something here as string is not a time
            End Try
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Still nothing is displayed on label7.text

Comment: @vigneshs I think it should be `If dr.Read() Then` statement if you are reading only one record and make sure the query returns any result

Comment: may be your time is more than 24 hours. edited the code to accomodate

Comment: still no improvement

Comment: i have added the picture may help you

Comment: put a break point at Dim dataTime As String = dr("Total_Time").ToString statement. Then debug step by step. dataTime should have string sent from db, then tt and other should get the value in Timespan.

Comment: is it ok to drop the milli second part of the time i.e. "18:41:14.8700000" can be "18:41:14" ?

Comment: @MukulVarshney no problem

Comment: i hope you are using the 2nd code, i.e. more than 24:00:00

Comment: did u gave a try ? TotalHours changed to TotalMinutes.

Comment: @mukul sorry i was not feeling well i tried ur code but there is not effect and my time is not more than 24hr its just some couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep switching to strings... and use a Timespan

If your label never changes then the routine must be erroring out, examine the error from the catch statement. However from your image it looks like Other has no value.

And you should **ALWAYS** test for dbnull when using databases. DBNull has some weird behaviours in Math and Boolean comparisons.

Replace your while loop with this

```
    If Not Dr.read OrElse IsDBNull(Dr("Total_time")) OrElse IsDBNull(Dr("Other")) Then
        Label7.text = "ERR"
    Else
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(dr("Total_time").ToString)
        Label7.text = (ts.TotalMinutes * Dr("Other")).ToString
    End If
```

PS: Your question says multiply by Other but your form/code says Add... I went with the question.

Comment: it is throwing ERR

Comment: I was fallen sick and i am not able to work for sum day, but i am alright now and i have tried all the above codes and its not working

Comment: it is showing err in the label7.text can u help me please

Comment: If you are getting ERR, break at the IF line and see which condition it is failing on.