# Event handler scope issue

Tags: vb.net, events, scope, addhandler

I've been struggling with this for hours.  Hopefully some of you vb.net gurus can help restore my sanity.

Scenario : I have an object (mqtt_client) which exposes connect / disconnect events that I need to trap and deal with.  I need the object to be accessible from multiple subs / functions / modules in my code. so I'm declaring it Public within the enclosing class but outside a code block.

If I declare it outside the main sub like this :

```
Public mqtt_client = New MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient
Public Sub Ruptela_Server(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' Add Event Handlers for Connected and disconnected events
    AddHandler mqtt_client.Disconnected, AddressOf MQTTclient_disconnected_handler
    AddHandler mqtt_client.Connected, AddressOf MQTTclient_connected_handler
```

The addhandler fails as the events aren't exposed by mqtt_client and I'm not sure why.

However, If I do it this way :

```
 Public Sub Ruptela_Server(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim mqtt_client = New MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient
    ' Add Event Handlers for Connected and disconnected events
    AddHandler mqtt_client.Disconnected, AddressOf MQTTclient_disconnected_handler
    AddHandler mqtt_client.Connected, AddressOf MQTTclient_connected_handler
```

Then the addhandlers hook up fine, but then the object only has scope inside the sub and can't be access from a different module.

I can't put ALL of this code outside of the enclosing block as addhandler is a method and won't work there.

How should I be going about this?  Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Type inference only works for local variables, so while this gives `mqtt_client` the type of `.CreateManagedMqttClient` with `Option Infer On`:

```
Public Sub Ruptela_Server(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim mqtt_client = New MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient
```

this gives it the type `Object`:

```
Public mqtt_client = New MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient

Public Sub Ruptela_Server(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

Specify an explicit type for the field with `As`, and [enable `Option Explicit` at the project level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076851/can-i-set-option-explicit-and-option-strict-on-a-project-solution-level) to avoid future problems. (`Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` should always be on for all source.)