# How can I produce the exact decimal values

Tags: vb.net, decimal

Code:

Dim mp as Decimal

mp = 2056834 / 36
MsgBox(mp, vbInformation)

Output: 57134.2777777778

I was expecting the output to be:

Output: 57134.27777777778

What suppose to be the problem on why it was short of a decimal point?

Comment: Use `mp = 2056834D / 36D`. You're currently using `Double` division.

Comment: You should enable [`Option Strict`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) so that the compiler prevents you from doing those kinds of mistakes. See [What do Option Strict and Option Explicit do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454552/8967612) and [Can I set Option Explicit and Option Strict on a Project/Solution level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076851/8967612)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between decimal, float and double in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim mp As Decimal

mp = Math.Round(CDec(2056834) / CDec(36), 11)
MsgBox(mp, vbInformation)
```

This will produce the expected output: `57134.27777777778`

Comment: `CDec` is useful when dealing with variables or expressions. In this case, the OP is dealing with literals, so `Math.Round(2056834D / 36D, 11)` should be fine.

Comment: I might use CDec for future use. Thank you guys